# does a wireless adapter work in my tv android box to boost wifi signal

Tags: wi-fi

I would like to boost the wifi signal coming into my tv android with a Tp-Link 600 does this work.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. I'd expect the Wi-Fi transceiver and antenna in your TV to be higher-gain than that in a USB Wi-Fi adapter, simply because the TV has more room for a large antenna and more stable power. Using an external Wi-Fi adapter would only improve things if

1. the TV is in a fully enclosed case, and you can mount the adapter outside the case; or
2. the TV was very cheap and badly designed.